# Ruby file permission issues on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, vagrant

I am trying to modify the the C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts file on windows through ruby code. When the file is opened in a "w" or "a" mode it gives the error

```
irb(main):001:0> @path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\etc\\hosts"
=> "C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\etc\\hosts"
irb(main):002:0> File.open(@path, "w")
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\
hosts
        from (irb):2:in `initialize'
        from (irb):2:in `open'
        from (irb):2
        from c:/Ruby21/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

On Windows 8 I have given Full control to the hosts file for the following users

```
USERS
ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES
ADMINISTRATORS
SYSTEM
```

I have verified that I can modify the hosts file through notepad after giving these permissions. 
I also tried running irb through a cmd prompt which has been started with administrator privileges but get the same error.

The original problem I was facing was running the vagranthostsupdater plugin which modifies the hosts file. vagrant fails with similar error in the hosts file modification step. I dug into the code and saw it failing at ruby file opening command, even though the hosts file has all the administrator permissions.